# How do I load an image for use as an openGL texture with LWJGL?

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I am trying to load an image as a texture for openGL using the LWJGL library. From what I found out so far, I need to pass the texture as a ByteBuffer to openGL. What I have right now is some code that correctly loads an image, and stores it in a BufferedImage object. The thing is, I have no clue how to get from a BufferedImage to a ByteBuffer that contains data in the right format for use with openGL (as input for the function GL11.glTexImage2D()).
Help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a method from the Space Invaders example that does what you want.  (I think)

```
/**
 * Convert the buffered image to a texture
 */
private ByteBuffer convertImageData(BufferedImage bufferedImage) {
    ByteBuffer imageBuffer;
    WritableRaster raster;
    BufferedImage texImage;

    ColorModel glAlphaColorModel = new ComponentColorModel(ColorSpace
            .getInstance(ColorSpace.CS_sRGB), new int[] { 8, 8, 8, 8 },
            true, false, Transparency.TRANSLUCENT, DataBuffer.TYPE_BYTE);

    raster = Raster.createInterleavedRaster(DataBuffer.TYPE_BYTE,
            bufferedImage.getWidth(), bufferedImage.getHeight(), 4, null);
    texImage = new BufferedImage(glAlphaColorModel, raster, true,
            new Hashtable());

    // copy the source image into the produced image
    Graphics g = texImage.getGraphics();
    g.setColor(new Color(0f, 0f, 0f, 0f));
    g.fillRect(0, 0, 256, 256);
    g.drawImage(bufferedImage, 0, 0, null);

    // build a byte buffer from the temporary image
    // that be used by OpenGL to produce a texture.
    byte[] data = ((DataBufferByte) texImage.getRaster().getDataBuffer())
            .getData();

    imageBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(data.length);
    imageBuffer.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    imageBuffer.put(data, 0, data.length);
    imageBuffer.flip();

    return imageBuffer;
}
```

Comment: I've already figured it out, thanks :)
I'll just mark the answer as answered for the effort

Comment: To future visitors, I found that @Displee's solution had the same effect but was slightly more verbose. Most of the stuff regarding the color model and copying the image can be handled using `getRGB`.

Answer (score 5):

A more straightforward approach to the previous answers is to use `image.getRGB` to do the color model conversion. Here is an excerpt from the Java 8 [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#getRGB-int-int-int-int-int:A-int-int-) on `getRGB`:

> Returns an array of integer pixels in the default RGB color model (`TYPE_INT_ARGB`) and default sRGB color space, from a portion of the image data. Color conversion takes place if the default model does not match the image ColorModel. There are only 8-bits of precision for each color component in the returned data when using this method.

```java
public static ByteBuffer imageToBuffer(BufferedImage image) {
    int[] pixels = image.getRGB(0, 0, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), null, 0, image.getWidth());
    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(pixels.length * 4);
    for (int pixel : pixels) {
        buffer.put((byte) ((pixel >> 16) & 0xFF));
        buffer.put((byte) ((pixel >> 8) & 0xFF));
        buffer.put((byte) (pixel & 0xFF));
        buffer.put((byte) (pixel >> 24) & 0xFF);
    }
    buffer.flip();
    return buffer;
}
```

The returned buffer is `GL_RGBA` of `GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE`.

Comment: I found, this was the most reliable and verbose solution even when compared to the higher voted answers. `getRGB` handles all the edge cases for you by standardizing the output to `TYPE_INT_ARGB` in sRGB color space. It can then be followed by `glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, yourDesiredImageType, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer)`.

Comment: I like this answer. I think `(pixel >> 24)` should be `((pixel >> 24) & 0xFF))` though.

Comment: You are correct. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2):

I used the solution above by Ron but the colors of the image when applied as a texture were incorrect, which means, the accepted solution will probably not produce same results for all kinds of images.

Trying to fix the problem with the color, I tried to use the `ColorModel` of the original `BufferedImage`, which can be accessed by calling the `BufferedImage#getColorModel`. But, it gave me an exception that the `ColorModel` of the original image is incompatible with the `WritableRaster` object.

I looked for a solution for this and I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18999430/with-bufferedimages-when-creating-a-writableraster-how-do-you-ensure-that-it-wi) one. Instead of calling `Raster.createInterleavedRaster` to create a `WritableRaster`, I used `ColorModel#createCompatibleWritableRaster`.

Hope this helps. Here's the code:

```
public static ByteBuffer load(BufferedImage bufferedImage) {

    WritableRaster raster = bufferedImage.getColorModel().createCompatibleWritableRaster
        (bufferedImage.getWidth(), bufferedImage.getHeight());
    BufferedImage textureImage = new BufferedImage(bufferedImage.getColorModel(), raster,
        true, new Hashtable<>());

    Graphics graphics = textureImage.getGraphics();
    graphics.setColor(new Color(0, 0, 0));
    graphics.fillRect(0, 0, 256, 256);
    graphics.drawImage(bufferedImage, 0, 0, null);

    byte[] data = ((DataBufferByte) textureImage.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();

    ByteBuffer imageBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(data.length);
    imageBuffer.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    imageBuffer.put(data, 0, data.length);
    imageBuffer.flip();

    return imageBuffer;
}
```

Comment: This approach does not work if the data buffer is not a `DataBufferByte`. In my code I had created an image with type `TYPE_INT_ARGB` and found that it used `DataBufferInt`. @Displee's solution is able to handle these edge cases.

Answer (score 0):

We also can do it in Shader.

```
BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

DataBufferInt dbb = (DataBufferInt) image.getRaster().getDataBuffer();
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, id);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, w, h, 0,   GL_RGBA,   GL_UNSIGNED_INT_8_8_8_8,dbb.getData());
```

GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER:

```
#version 130

uniform sampler2D tex;

in vec2 texCoordsVarying;
out vec4 color;

void main() {
  vec4 c2 = texture(tex, texCoordsVarying);
  color = vec4(c2.g, c2.b, c2.a, c2.r);
}
```

The method given by @Displee , uses CPU time, If you just load texture once it is OK.
If you update the texture every frame, you could use Shader, it use GPU and less time(1/4 time I tested on my PC)