# How to save images in the memory with LWJGL?

Tags: java, image, opengl, textures, lwjgl

I've been using java regular graphics device, awt and swing stuff, with Graphics, Graphics2D, and etc. for a while, and then a started to watch a series of tutorials about LWJGL. I really enjoyed and decided to redo one of my games in that system; I thought, since I already had the logic, it would be easy. And I just ran into one conceptual problem.

In this specific case, I had a class Box that represent a box, but I drew it with images, thus making the borders. I had 9 images, one for the center (that was just a plain color 1 pixel width image), 4 for the sides and 4 for the corners. I had all this images in a BufferedImage array, that was static, because it was the same for all boxes. Then, each box had a global BufferedImage, in which I drew the box, that is really slow process, because I have to draw a image in every part of the box. Then, in the real draw method (that recieved the Graphics g), I just drew the BufferedImage in the correct position. Since the size of the box didn't change once it was created, I just had to 'create' the box image once in the constructor.

I couldn't figure how to do that with LWJGL, because the gl_ methods (glBegin(), glVertex2i()) will always draw on the screen, even though I had never specified that. So how do I draw into a image and how do I store it on the memory (using a BufferedImage too), and also, how do I draw it on the screen when I want? I found that LWJGL uses textures, and I make the first static array of BufferedImage a static array of Texture, and then saved each one of the 9 textures inside it correctly. Is it the right way? What about the global BufferedImage, should it be a global Texture? In that case, how to 'draw' on the texture?

Answer (score 1):

The technique you're looking for is usually called 'Render to Texture' (RTT). You create an opengl framebuffer, attach a texture to it, bind your framebuffer, and then issue normal draw calls. With your framebuffer bound, the draw calls will be drawn directly into your texture. You then unbind the framebuffer and use your texture as a normal texture.

With these search terms I'm sure you can find tutorials on the internet about exactly how to do this.

I'm just curious though, what does your box look like that it can't be drawn with a normal texture? Maybe there's an easier way to go about it.

Comment: Thank you very much, I am searching about it right now and I am sure it will be very usefull. About the box, maybe I just don't know exactly how texture works, but it is like this: each box you create has a different size, and they all have the same fixed size borders. So I guessed the better way was to create 9 images, like I said. I don't know if there is a better way - I imagined that with a static texture the border would grow proporcionally with the box, and I don't want that.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this [LWJGL texture tutorial](http://www.lwjgl.org/wiki/index.php?title=Slick-Util_Library_-_Part_1_-_Loading_Images_for_LWJGL), from their wiki.
In this example they use the [Slick-Util Library](http://slick.cokeandcode.com/), which makes it much easier to create a texture from an image.

---

Alternatively you can generate the texture by yourself:

```
BufferedImage bufferedImage = ...;
ByteBuffer textureBuffer = convertImageData(bufferedImage);

int texture = glGenTextures();
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);

int pixelFormat;
if (bufferedImage.getColorModel().hasAlpha()) {
    pixelFormat = GL_RGBA;
} else {
    pixelFormat = GL_RGB;
}

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, 
        bufferedImage.getWidth(), bufferedImage.getHeight(), 0,
        pixelFormat, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, textureBuffer);
```

Aaaaaand see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5194325/how-do-i-load-an-image-for-use-as-an-opengl-texture-with-lwjgl) for convertImageData() i've written before. (in his code there are a few lines that you can remove)

To draw the texture: see line 97 of [LWJGL Space Invaders](http://www.lwjgl.org/wiki/index.php?title=Examples:SpaceInvaders_Sprite).

Comment: I tryed, and it doesn't give any errors, but it yet doesn't work. It generates the BufferedImage OK (I saved it on a file just to see), but the square appears with a messed up texture. I am trying to find the error, it's surely some mistake I did in other parts of the code. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

In OpenGL, scaling is dirt cheap. You don't need need to pre-generate anything. You can put all your images in one texture and use texture mapping to place and scale them properly as you are drawing them to the screen.

If you already have a solution using `BufferedImage`, keep it that way. Generating this image on GPU won't save you much time. Generate the image using awt, create texture out of it and draw it to the screen using LWJGL.

If you really want to do it, you can save things from screen to a texture using `glCopyPixels`. But I wouldn't start learning OpenGL from that. Avoid transferring the image to main memory (keep it in a texture not BufferedImage), sending data between CPU and GPU can be really slow.

Comment: I looked for texture mapping and I couldn't find any way to do what I want (but didn't find any great tutorials either, just some specific points). I tried to generate a texture from a BufferedImage, but it didn't work; I sure the BI is created correctly and I used a method I copied from the Internet, but it shows a white box. I was trying to use texture mapping, another sugestion I recieved, but coudn't do anything good with it neither.